# Inclusion of a covariate that has no variation in treatment group

Tags: regression

I am interested in the effect of an intervention on an outcome. We have set up a quasi-experimental design where we are comparing participants that received certain inputs to participants that did not receive the inputs because there were not enough to go around but they would have wanted to if there was. However, not all comparison participants in our sample would have wanted to take up the inputs (which we have data on).

So in our sample, we have variation on a variable called interest (representing desire to use inputs) in the comparison group but no variation in the treatment group (all participants had interest).

I'm trying to understand intuitively the difference between filtering the sample on interest and only comparing those where interest==1 versus including interest as a covariate. My instinct is that including it as a covariate won't help with power because there's no variation in one of the groups. And also that it wouldn't affect the coefficient on treatment for the same reason.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: So, to be clear, you let users select into use of this new feature?  I'm just not sure what the "interest" variable means.  Did those who have interest =1 actually use the feature?  It would be beneficial to see some of the data, even if that data is fabricated.

Comment: Yes so all treatment units have interest==1. I've updated the post with a picture of some fake data. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're described correctly, you should exclude those without interest from the control group, i.e. remove them from your analysis.

Those without interest in receiving the treatment are likely fundamentally different from those who are interested in receiving the treatment and this difference is probably also linked to your outcome. That would make "interest" a confounder.

Having excluding these observations, you're then better positioned to argue that the only difference between treatment and your comparison group is that the treatment "randomly" wasn't available for the comparison group.

Comment: Right! But does controlling for interest do the same thing? Or does it not really make a difference because there's no variation in interest in the treatment group?

Comment: Do you mean controlling for interest by added it as a variable in a regression? I guess if you're using a linear regression and you make an interaction between interest with the outcome that would amount to the same thing.